# Python sort array of string with integers inside

Tags: python, list

How i can use python to sort the list format

```
format=["12 sheet","4 sheet","48 sheet","6 sheet", "busrear", "phonebox","train"]
```

like this way

```
format =["4 sheet", "6 sheet", "12 sheet", "48 sheet", "busrear, "phonebox", "train"]
```

edit: If the array is a list of list then how can we do that like this one

`format=[[1L, u'12 sheet', 0],[2L, u'4 sheet', 0], [3L, u'48 sheet', 0], [4L, u'6 sheet', 0 [5L, u'Busrear', 0], [6L, u'phonebox', 0], [7L, u'train', 0]]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
>>> fmts =["12 sheet","4 sheet","48 sheet","6 sheet", "busrear", "phonebox","train"]
>>> fmts.sort(key=lambda x: (int(x.split(None, 1)[0]) if x[:1].isdigit() else 999, x))
>>> fmts
['4 sheet', '6 sheet', '12 sheet', '48 sheet', 'busrear', 'phonebox', 'train']
```

[`format`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#format) is a builtin function. Do not use it as a variable name. It will shadow the builtin function.

Comment: @thefourtheye, Used `x[:1]` to prevent IndexError.

Comment: Wouldn't that be better if `else x` instead of `else 999`?

Comment: @thefourtheye, You can't compare `int` with `str` in Python 3.x; causes `TypeError: unorderable types: str() < int()`

Comment: @thefourtheye, Specific version is not mentioned. So I provided a solutioni that can be run both in Python 2.x/3.x.

Comment: Hey thanks for answer but if the list will be a list of list then how we will sort it

Comment: @question, What is the expected output for the given list?

Answer (score 0):

you can create an intermediate array that looks like the following:

```
intermediate = [(12, "sheet"), (4, "sheet"), ... ]
```

then you can use sorted on `intermediate` which will sort by first value by default.

then get back to your format.