# Python sort list of list containing integer and string with integers inside

Tags: python, list, sorting

How i can use python to sort the list format

```
format=["12 sheet","4 sheet","48 sheet","6 sheet", "busrear", "phonebox","train"]
```

like this way

```
format =["4 sheet", "6 sheet", "12 sheet", "48 sheet", "busrear", "phonebox", "train"]
```

whose answer is here [Python sort array of string with integers inside](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22060090/python-sort-array-of-string-with-integers-inside)

but If the array is a list of list then how can we do that like this one

```
format=[[1, '12 sheet', 0],[2, '4 sheet', 0], [3, '48 sheet', 0], [4, '6 sheet', 0 [5, 'Busrear', 0], [6, 'phonebox', 0], [7, 'train', 0]]
```

I Need the result to be like this

```
format=[[2, '4 sheet', 0],[4, '6 sheet', 0],[1, '12 sheet', 0],[3, '48 sheet', 0],[5, 'Busrear', 0], [6, 'phonebox', 0], [7, 'train', 0]]
```

Comment: if its list of list then you have to decide on which bases you have to sort? on first index base of list or other?

Comment: there inbuilt methods for lists like sort() which just use assemble ints first then deal with chars and so forth

Comment: Are you asking how to sort a list or how to sort a list of lists with sorting key inside the inner list?

Comment: I am just asking how to sort according to string present in each sub list

Comment: and why the long and unicode?

Comment: just ignore that thing

Comment: How should `[[1, '1 foo', 0], [1, '2 bar', 0], [1, '3 foo', 0]]` be sorted - should the `foo` items get grouped together or not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this:

```
lst = [[1L, u'12 sheet', 0],
       [2L, u'4 sheet', 0],
       [3L, u'48 sheet', 0],
       [4L, u'6 sheet', 0],
       [5L, u'Busrear', 0],
       [6L, u'phonebox', 0],
       [7L, u'train', 0]]

def sortby(x):
    try:
        return int(x[1].split(' ')[0])
    except ValueError:
        return float('inf')

lst.sort(key=sortby)
print lst
```

Output:

```
[[2L, u'4 sheet', 0], [4L, u'6 sheet', 0], [1L, u'12 sheet', 0], [3L, u'48 sheet', 0], [5L, u'Busrear', 0], [6L, u'phonebox', 0], [7L, u'train', 0]]
```

You can always use fancier list comprehension but readability counts. Which is why you might not feel like modifying the cool [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22060090/python-sort-array-of-string-with-integers-inside) by falsetru for this slightly changed task.

Answer (score 3):

You can trivially sort a list of strings with built-in `sorted` method. Even if the objects in your list are more complex, you can still use `sorted`. Just pass a custom key parameter to use the second item from the inner list as the key in ordering comparisons:

```
result = sorted(format, key=lambda x: x[1])
```

Finally switch to your sorting function natsorted (from natsort package) and you end up with the desired, naturally sorted, result list:

```
from natsort import natsorted
result = natsorted(format, key=lambda x: x[1])
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `sorted` or `list.sort`

```
>>> format.sort(key=lambda x: (x[1]))
[[1L, u'12 sheet', 0], [2L, u'4 sheet', 0], [3L, u'48 sheet', 0], [4L, u'6 sheet', 0], [5L, u'Busrear', 0], [6L, u'phonebox', 0], [7L, u'train', 0]]
```

Comment: How is this sorted as per the requirement?

Answer (score 1):

The same solution can be used here

```
print sorted(format_data, key=lambda x: (int(x[1].split(None, 1)[0]) if x[1][:1].isdigit() else 999, x))
```

Note the `x[1]` instead of just `x`. `x[1]` means the second element in `x`.

**Result:**

```
[[2, '4 sheet', 0],
 [4, '6 sheet', 0],
 [1, '12 sheet', 0],
 [3, '48 sheet', 0],
 [5, 'Busrear', 0],
 [6, 'phonebox', 0],
 [7, 'train', 0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [5,1,"a","A",2]
a = list(map(int,filter(lambda x:x.isdigit(),sorted(map(str,a)))))+list(filter(lambda x:x.isalpha(),sorted(map(str,a))))
print(a)
```

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue